# Pyspark Create New Tables In Loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a massive table where each customer is assigned a value 1, 2, 3, ....15. I'm trying to then create 15 new individual tables, split based on that assigned value. So table 1 will have all user with assigned value 1, table 2 all users with assigned value 2 and so on.

input:

| user_id | spend | user_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 50 | 1 |
| B | 75 | 1 |
| C | 100 | 2 |
| D | 25 | 3 |
| E | 50 | 3 |
| F | 30 | 4 |

results:

| user_id | spend | user_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 50 | 1 |
| B | 75 | 1 |

| user_id | spend | user_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 100 | 2 |

| user_id | spend | user_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D | 25 | 3 |
| E | 50 | 3 |

| user_id | spend | user_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | 30 | 4 |

`user_list = [1,2,3,4]`

`for user_value in user_list: SQL_tbl = spark.sql('''SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE user_value = '{}' '''.format(user_list)) SQL_tbl.write.mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable('''temp_tbl_{}'''.format(user_list), format='delta')`

It's not iterating through and instead just populating the string SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE cluster_rank = [1,2,3,4] which ends up with an empty table that won't save. how do I get it to actually iterate through?

Comment: Should `cluster_list` and `user_list` be replaced with `user_value`?

Comment: @werner--apologies, that was a typo/forgetting to update naming convention on my part. should be fixed now.